# poedit translation tool and Zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, poedit

I am trying to execute the poEdit tool but when I try to save the .po file I get this error:

```
19:12:53: Pipe creation failed (error 24: Too many open files)
19:12:53: Failed to execute '/Applications/Poedit.app/Contents/MacOS/msgcat'

19:12:53: Cannot execute program: "/Applications/Poedit.app/Contents/MacOS/msgcat" --force-po -o "/var/folders/7f/4kk4rqf902158ykl870lqq9w0000gn/T/poeditjeG0Rf/241merged_chunks.pot"  "/var/folders/7f/4kk4rqf902158ykl870lqq9w0000gn/T/poeditjeG0Rf/0extracted.pot" "/var/folders/7f/4kk4rqf902158ykl870lqq9w0000gn/T/poeditjeG0Rf/1extracted.pot" "/var/folders/7f/4kk4rqf902158ykl870lqq9w0000gn/T/poeditjeG0Rf/2extracted.pot" "/var/folders/7f/4kk4rqf902158ykl870lqq9w0000gn/T/poeditjeG0Rf/3extracted.pot" "/var/folders/7f/4kk4rqf902158ykl870lqq9w0000gn/T/poeditjeG0Rf/4extracted.pot" "/var/folders/7f/4kk4rqf902158ykl870lqq9w0000gn/T/poeditjeG0Rf/5extracted.pot" "/var/folders/7f/4kk4rqf902158ykl870lqq9w0000gn/T/poeditjeG0Rf/6extracted.pot" "/var/folders/7f/4kk4rqf902158ykl870lqq9w0000gn/T/poeditjeG0Rf/7extracted.pot" "/var/folders/7f/4kk4rqf902158ykl870lqq9w0000gn/T/poeditjeG0Rf/8extracted.pot" "/var/folders/7f/4kk4rqf902158ykl870lqq9w0000gn/T/poeditjeG0Rf/9extracted.pot" "/var/folders/7f/4kk4rqf902158ykl870lqq9w0000gn/T/poeditjeG0Rf/10extracted.pot" "/var/folders/7f/4kk4rqf902158ykl870lqq9w0000gn/T/poeditjeG0Rf/11extracted.pot" "/var/folders/7f/4kk4rqf902158ykl870lqq9w0000gn/T/poeditjeG0Rf/12extracted.pot" "/var/folders/7f/4kk4rqf902158ykl870lqq9w0000gn/T/poeditjeG0Rf/13extracted.pot" "/var/folders/7f/4kk4rqf902158ykl870lqq9w0000gn/T/poeditjeG0Rf/14extracted.pot" "/var/folders/7f/4kk4rqf902158ykl870lqq9w0000gn/T/poeditjeG0Rf/15extracted.pot" "/var/folders/7f/4kk4rqf902158ykl870lqq9w0000gn/T/poeditjeG0Rf/16extracted.pot" "/var/folders/7f/4kk4rqf902158ykl870lqq9w0000gn/T/poeditjeG0Rf/17extracted.pot" "/var/folders/7f/4kk4rqf902158ykl870lqq9w0000gn/T/poeditjeG0Rf/18extracted.pot" "/var/folders/7f/4kk4rqf902158ykl870lqq9w0000gn/T/poeditjeG0Rf/19extracted.pot" "/var/folders/7f/4kk4rqf902158ykl870lqq9w0000gn/T/poeditjeG0Rf/20extracted.pot" "/var/folders/7f/4kk4rqf902158ykl870lqq9w0000gn/T/poeditjeG0Rf/21extracted.pot" "/var/folders/7f/4kk4rqf902158ykl870lqq9w0000gn/T/poeditjeG0Rf"
19:12:53: Failed to merge gettext catalogues.
19:12:53: Entries in the catalogue are probably incorrect.
19:12:53: Updating the catalog failed. Click on 'Details >>' for details.
```